# React Native app style not rendering on xcode simulator but working on Android Studio?

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, android-studio

So I have a basic react native chat application that runs on both android studio and Xcode ios simulator. I am using expo. But the Xcode ios simulator is not rendering some styles as you can see. The android emulator is showing proper alignment for all the text and border radius for each message box. What is the issue?

[image: THIS WORKS FINE - ANDROID]

[image: THIS IS THE PROBLEM - IOS]

```
    function ChatMessage(props) {
  const { to,message,from,time } = props.message;
  const messageClass = from === 'Ram' ? 'sent' : 'received';

  const timeStamp = () =>{
    return( 
    <View>
      <Text style={{fontSize:12,color:'black',alignSelf:'flex-end'}}>{time}</Text>
    </View>
    )
  }

  return (
  <>
    {/* <View className ={`message ${messageClass}`}> */}
    <View style={[styles.messageContainer, messageClass === 'sent' ? styles.sent : styles.received ]}>
      <Text style={[styles.message, messageClass === 'sent' ? styles.sentMessage : styles.receivedMessage ]}>
        
        {messageClass === 'received' && <NameStamp from={from}/>}//PROBLEM HERE. CODE OF NAMESTAMP BELOW
        {messageClass === 'received' && "\n"}
        <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>
        {message}
        </Text>
        {"\n"}
        {timeStamp()} //PROBLEM HERE CODE OF TIMESTAMP ABOVE
        {/*invoke timeStamp function */}
      </Text>
    </View>
  </>
  )
}

//THIS COMPONENT IS ~Ghanshayam IN THE SCREEN. NOT ALIGNING //PROPERLY
const NameStamp = (props) =>{
    return(
      <View>
        <Text style={{color:'grey',fontSize:12,alignSelf:'flex-end'}}>
          ~{props.from}
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }




const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor:'#d4e4f7',
    flex:1,
    
  },
  header:{
    backgroundColor:'#236ab9',
    flexDirection:'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
    flex:1,
    
  },
  main:{
    backgroundColor:'#d4e4f7',
    padding:10,
    flex:5,
  },
  form:{
    backgroundColor:'#236ab9',
    flex:1,
    flexDirection:'row'
  },
  input:{
    flex:4,
    color:'white',
    padding:5,
    fontSize:22,
  },
  text:{
    // margin:'0 auto',
    color:'white',
    fontSize:20, 
  },
  message:{
    lineHeight:24,
    padding:15,
    marginBottom:12,
    borderRadius:25,
    overflow:'hidden', //THIS FIXED THE BORDER RADIUS
    position:'relative',
    color:'white',
    textAlign:'left'
  },
  messageContainer:{
    flexDirection:'row',
    alignItems:'center',
  },
  sent:{
    flexDirection:'row-reverse'
  },
  sentMessage:{
    color:'white',
    backgroundColor:'#0b93f6',
    alignSelf:'flex-end'
  },
  receivedMessage:{
    backgroundColor:'white',
    color:'black'
  }
});
```

Comment: can you add your styles and little bit of code...

Comment: The reason I didnt add any style and code was because I expected that if it runs fine on android then it should run the same on ios as they have the same exact code

Comment: yes i got your concerns, but if we cannot see the code we may not be able to tell you what the issue is and how we can resolve it...

Comment: have u added overflow: 'hidden' to the item component where u u have added borderRadius?

Comment: overflow:'hidden' fixed the border radius thanks. But the alignment of ~Ghanshayam & the timestamp is still not working. I have added the code. THANKS A LOT

Comment: please add the styling i will add the answer otherwise i wont be able to help you..

Comment: I have added the styling. You can see in the time stamp component and the name stamp component. And other styling if you scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the updated code as for your need i have included snack link so you check that its working in both ios, android platforms

[snack demo link](https://snack.expo.dev/@ashwith00/grumpy-truffle)

code:

```
function ChatMessage(props) {
  const { to, message, from, time } = props.message;
  const messageClass = from === 'Ram' ? 'sent' : 'received';

  const timeStamp = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 12,
            color: messageClass === 'sent' ? 'white' : 'black',
            alignSelf: 'flex-end',
          }}>
          {time}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View
      style={[
        styles.messageContainer,
        messageClass === 'sent' ? styles.sent : styles.received,
      ]}>
      {messageClass === 'received' && <NameStamp from={from} />}
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.message,
          messageClass === 'sent' ? styles.sentMessage : styles.receivedMessage,
        ]}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{message}</Text>
      </Text>
      {timeStamp()}
    </View>
  );
}

const NameStamp = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={{ color: 'grey', fontSize: 12, alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}>
        ~{props.from}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#d4e4f7',
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 70,
  },
  header: {
    backgroundColor: '#236ab9',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  main: {
    backgroundColor: '#d4e4f7',
    padding: 10,
    flex: 5,
  },
  form: {
    backgroundColor: '#236ab9',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  input: {
    flex: 4,
    color: 'white',
    padding: 5,
    fontSize: 22,
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  message: {
    lineHeight: 24,
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'left',
  },
  received: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
  },
  messageContainer: {
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    padding: 15,
    marginBottom: 12,
    borderRadius: 25,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    minWidth: 160,
    maxWidth: 220, // define min, max width
  },
  sent: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    backgroundColor: '#0b93f6',
  },
  sentMessage: {
    color: 'white',
   
  },
  receivedMessage: {
    color: 'black',
  },
});
```